# Unable to convert a list of strings to a list of integers-- LeetCode Question 1022 (Sum of Root to Leaf Binary Numbers)

Tags: python, binary, binary-tree

currently solving this leetcode question (https://leetcode.com/problems/sum-of-root-to-leaf-binary-numbers/)

and this is my current solution (unfinished):

```
class Solution:
    def sumRootToLeaf(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        if not root:
            return []
        if not root.left and not root.right:
            return [str(root.val)]
        

        elements = []
        elements.extend(str(root.val) + i for i in self.sumRootToLeaf(root.left)) 
        elements.extend(str(root.val) + i for i in self.sumRootToLeaf(root.right)) 
        
        
        nums = [int(element) for element in elements]
        
        return nums
```

i have an issue returning the "nums" array

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

but have no such issue returning the "elements" array:

```
['100', '101', '110', '111']
```

- also, when i try to `print (elements)`, it outputs the following:
  https://gyazo.com/9c6020db886e43fb0d36873216ea2340
- in addition, when i try to run this:

```
class Solution:
    def sumRootToLeaf(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        if not root:
            return []
        if not root.left and not root.right:
            return [str(root.val)]
        

        elements = []
        elements.extend(str(root.val) + i for i in self.sumRootToLeaf(root.left)) 
        elements.extend(str(root.val) + i for i in self.sumRootToLeaf(root.right)) 
        
        
        for element in elements:
            return element
```

it outputs `10` instead of the expected `100`

what is the cause of this?

EDIT:

I also tried

```
class Solution:
    def sumRootToLeaf(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        if not root:
            return []
        if not root.left and not root.right:
            return [str(root.val)]
        

        elements = []
        elements.extend(str(root.val) + str(i) for i in self.sumRootToLeaf(root.left)) 
        elements.extend(str(root.val) + str(i) for i in self.sumRootToLeaf(root.right)) 
        
        
        nums = [int(element) for element in elements]
        
        return nums
```

and i could output the “nums” array, but it was not correct:

it output this `[10, 11, 110, 111]`

Comment: I guess the issue is here `elements.extend(str(root.val) + i for i in self.sumRootToLeaf(root.left))`.

Comment: i tried elements.extend(str(root.val) + str(i) for i in self.sumRootToLeaf(root.left)) but it still doesn’t work as intended